# How Do You Run the ENTIRE Javascript Page From An Button In HTML?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to make all my Javascript Page code from JSBin to work automatically upon the clicking of a button. Problems include not being able to run the code because it says I have multiple variables in my script that do not work together and not being able to put it all in HTML because console.log doesn't work. I tried a couple different ideas, but sadly, I am unable to do it correctly.

My Code Is:

```
var name = prompt('So what is your name?');

var confirmName = confirm('So your name is ' + UCFL(name) + '?');

function UCFL(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

if (confirmName === true) {
var start = confirm('Good. Lets start the roleplay, Sir ' + UCFL(name) + '. Are you  
ready?');
}
if (confirmName === false) {
var name = prompt('Than what is your name?');
var confirmNamed = confirm('So your name is ' + UCFL(name) + '?');
}

if (confirmNamed === true) {
var start = confirm('Good. Lets start the roleplay, Sir ' + UCFL(name) + '. Are you    
ready?');
}
if (confirmNamed === false) {
var name = prompt('Than what is your name?');
var confirmName = confirm('So your name is ' + UCFL(name) + '?');
if (confirmName === true) {
var start = confirm('Good. Lets start the roleplay, Sir ' + UCFL(name) + '. Are you
ready?');
}
if (confirmName === false) {
alert('Oh, guess what? I do not even fucking care what your name is anymore. Lets just 
start..');
var start = confirm('Are you ready?');
}
}

if (start === true) {
var x = console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));
if (x === 1) {
    alert('You are an dwarf in a time of great  disease.');
    alert('');
}

}
```

And this is what I want you to fix:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Start The Game" onclick="" />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have no clue what the actual question is. What are you trying to accomplish? What's the expected result? How is the actual result different from it? Could your sample code possibly be simplified to show only the essence of your problem?

Comment: I am trying to make them connect on a click of the button to make the entire Javascript page run...

Comment: @user2103896 Well put it inside a function and then mention the function in the onclick (if you really have to do it inline like that) - http://jsfiddle.net/tAMfj/

Comment: Whenever I do that, it says it is out of scope and reused. Apparently, there are problems with that..

Comment: @user2103896 I don't see a javascript file in your HTML?

Comment: Press JSHint. Your answers will lay there and that is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an entry on JSBin suggesting many improvements to what you have now:

http://jsbin.com/epurul/3/edit

Visit the entry to test the code yourself. Here is the content, for convenience:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <button onclick="playGame()">Play Game</button>  
</body>
```

And JavaScript:

```
// Expose playGame as a top-level function so that it can be accessed in the
// onclick handler for the 'Play Game' button in your HTML.
window.playGame = function() {

  // I would generally recommend defining your functions before you use them.
  // (This is just a matter of taste, though.)
  function UCFL(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  }

  // Rather than capitalize name everywhere it is used, just do it once
  // and then use the result everywhere else.
  function getName(message) {
    return UCFL(prompt(message));
  }

  var name = getName('So what is your name?');

  // Don't repeat yourself:
  // If you're writing the same code in multiple places, try consolidating it
  // into one place.
  var nameAttempts = 0;
  while (!confirm('So your name is ' + name + '?') && ++nameAttempts < 3) {
    // Don't use 'var' again as your name variable is already declared.
    name = getName('Then what is your name?');
  }

  if (nameAttempts < 3) {
    alert('Good. Lets start the roleplay, Sir ' + name + '.');
  } else {
    alert("Oh, guess what? I do not even fucking care what your name is anymore. Let's just start...");
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a function, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script>
    function runGame() {
        // put your js code here
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Start The Game" onclick="runGame();" />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

It would also be a good idea to copy your js code to another file and import that using a script tag, for instance:

```
<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>
```